# When submitting an article to a journal, should the article be an attachment or a link to my blog?

Tags: submitting-work, email, feedback, hyperlink

I have a research article (not really an article with academic standards, but display my analysis nevertheless) and I would like to submit it to a journal (not an academic one either, but has reputation). I wonder if I should attach the article as an attachment or a link?

- **Attachment:** more trustworthy and convenient. But I would argue that opening a Word document is a pain in mobile, and isn't better than opening a link in computer
- **Link:** can introduce other articles in it, and can have tracking tail to know whether the link is opened or not

So it seems that submitting it as a link has more pro than as an attachment. I foresee that there will be a concern that including the tracking link is not respecting the readers, but I suspect that if they are running a website already, they also do that to others as well.

A side question: how to get much feedback for my article, if it's rejected?

Comment: It really depends on the journal. PNAS, for example, has protocols in place to submit a LaTeX file through Overleaf. Fiction journals have preferred manuscript formatting and file types. I imagine there is a page on the journal's site acknowledging this.

Comment: You can include links in a Word document or many other formats (Word still seems very popular for some types of publication). Putting a tracker in your article seems a bit pointless; you may know it has been opened but you don't know that it has been read or considered for publication, and it might even be triggered by automated email scanning or preview functionality. It's also possible to disable third-party trackers. As for how to get feedback, pay somebody.

Answer (score 2):

Step one is to check if your publisher has any submission guidelines.
If they have submission guidelines, it should tell you how to submit an article. It will also mention requirements to submission, such as format and additional information that's needed.

If you can't find submission guidelines, you can contact them first to ask.

And otherwise, when in doubt, do both. You lose nothing but a bit of bandwidth by sending both the attachment and a link.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an article or is it a blog post? If it's already been published on a blog, why would someone else want to publish it? You may have a reason. Make that clear.

Any reasonable publication isn't going to consider opening a Word document is a pain. I don't know what you mean by 'including the tracking link is not respecting the readers'.

Comment: "If it's already been published on a blog, why would someone else want to publish it?" – Wait, a blog post is just a medium for an author to send their work to others. I see it's no difference to a Word document sending via email. You can also send it to any other person. It doesn't guarantee any contract to any other publisher.

Comment: As for the inconvenience, I mean opening a Word document in phone doesn't zoom the word for you to easily read. But if it's a website, the browser can. As for the tracking link, say I send you the link `www.google.com` then I don't know whether you have clicked on it or not, or how much time you spend reading it. But if I send you `www.google.com/trackingcode`, I can know

Comment: If I'm editing a journal, I'm not going to be editing it on a phone. I am going to be using a computer with two screens.

Comment: A blog post is a publication. Therefore, things like 'first publication rights offered' don't apply. Other people can see a blog post.

Comment: Most journals (at least literary ones) will post on their website what their submission guidelines are. Some want everything in the email, some want attachments, some use electronic submissions. There isn't a general answer for this. Also, most of them are explicit about not accepting submissions which have been previously published. Most of those (not all) include anything that has been available on the internet that wasn't behind a password as "published." Check the guidelines. If you can't find guidelines on their site, drop them an email first.